# What's Popup Text and Popup Background in the command window properties for?

Tags: windows, command-line

When configuring command window properties in the 'Colors' tab we get -

1. Screen Text
2. Screen Background
3. Popup Text
4. Popup Background

Can anyone tell me what the difference is between the 'Screen' and 'Popup' sets of properties?

Looking up on the windows documentation all it says is that popup properties are used to specify popup window properties, which brings up the question of what the difference is between normal console windows and popup windows.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Press <kbd>F7</kbd> to display a command-line history: you'll see the history appears in a pop-up window, normally magenta on white.

It's just a modal dialog, overlaid on the normal console window, and it disappears when you press <kbd>Esc</kbd>, <kbd>↵ Enter</kbd>, or <kbd>←</kbd> <kbd>→</kbd>

The key bindings are as follows:
<kbd>Esc</kbd>: Cancel the command-line history dialog.
<kbd>↑</kbd> or <kbd>↓</kbd>: Select a command in the list.
<kbd>↵ Enter</kbd>: Execute the selected command immediately.
<kbd>←</kbd> or <kbd>→</kbd>: Load the selected command on the command line (so that you can edit it).